# Add additional annotations to existing helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to add some annotations to the metadata block of a service within an existing helm chart (I have to add an annotation for Prometheus so that the service is auto discovered). The chart (it is the neo4j chart) does not offer me a configuration that I can use to set annotations. I also looked into the yaml files and noticed that there is no variable I can use to insert something in the metadata block. The only solution I can see is that I have to fork the chart, insert the annotation data to the correct place and create my own chart out of it. Is that really the only solution or is there some trick I am missing that allows me to modify the helm chart without creating a new one?

Comment: If the Helm chart doesn't expose the annotation block (or part of it) as variables, then no, you can't do it without modifying the yamls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Helm 2, you are correct. Either you would have to fork the chart or pass it through another tool after rendering like Kustomize. Helm 3 has some planned features to improve this in the future.

Comment: Do you have a link to that planned feature?

Comment: https://github.com/helm/community/blob/master/helm-v3/001-charts.md#the-ext-directory The idea is that exts will be able to make arbitrary changes to child chart objects from Lua code.

Comment: I see there is very little docs about this feature. I am not sure if you can add annotations to K8s objects through this feature. Did you see it somewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1950 could be related also.

Comment: The feature has not yet been implemented so you can't use it yet.